# Convergence of $\chi_n = \mathbb{1}_{\{1,2,...,,n\}}$ in different topologies

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, dual-spaces

Let $X = l^2(\mathbb{N})$ and define $\chi_n = \mathbb{1}_{\{1,,2,...,n\}}$ and note that $ X = (l^\infty(\mathbb{N}))^*$. They are asking to show whether $(\chi_n)_n$ is convergent in the weak* topology and if so, give its limit. They then also ask if it is convergent in the weak topology. However, I don't really understand how these $\chi_n$ are defined or what they actually mean.

Comment: $\chi_1=(1,0,...,0,...)$, $\chi_2=(1,1,....)$, $\chi_3=(1,1,1,...)$ and so on.

Comment: I don't think that $ X = (l^\infty(\mathbb{N}))^*$ is correct